# How to convert value in crystal report to php?

Tags: php, crystal-reports

I want to retrieve min and max value shown on the crystal report to another new crystal report.
What i have on my crystal report :

```
 {@fmt_value} > TONUMBER({VW_Off_Value_Process.Max}) OR {@fmt_value} < TONUMBER({VW_Off_Value_Process.Min}) OR {VW_Off_Value_Process.Remark} <> ""
```

How to convert below using cake php?

```
{@fmt_value} > TONUMBER({VW_Off_Value_Process.Max})
```